# Getting 'missing left parenthesis' when creating unique index to global partition

Tags: oracle

I create index on my foreign key:

```
CREATE INDEX FK_SOME_TABLE ON SOME_TABLE(F_SOME_ID) 
LOCAL
LOGGING
TABLESPACE SOME_TABLESPACE
NOPARALLEL;
```

It works correctly.

I try to create unique index on primary key, but all time I get error about 
"missing left parenthesis", I red some issues about "missing left parenthesis" but I can't get solution.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX PK_SOME_TABLE ON SOME_TABLE
        (SOME_ID) 
          TABLESPACE SOME_TABLESPACE
        LOGGING
        GLOBAL PARTITION BY RANGE (SOME_ID)
          INTERVAL (1000)
          (
            PARTITION P_1 VALUES LESS THAN (1000)
          )
        NOPARALLEL;
```

Probably I omit parenthesis in an important place, but I really don't know where.
Could you give me some advices?

Comment: Without the interval it compiles...  From what I'm reading interval is set on the create table, not on the index.  but I'm a bit out of my league.

Comment: Have a look at the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_5012.htm#i2171607)

Comment: http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Interval_partitioning  Seems to state that Interval partitioning is NOT supported for index-organized tables.  But I'm not sure these concepts align to what you're doing here yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we use creating an `UNIQUE INDEX`  to `GLOBAL PARTITION BY RANGE` we can only use this options:

```
COMPRESS,
NOCMPRESS,
PCTFREE,
INITRANS,
MAXTRANS,
STORAGE,
TABLESPACE,
PARALLEL,
RECOVERABLE,
UNRECOVERABLE,
LOGGING,
NOLOGGING,
LOCAL,
GLOBAL
```

so as we see, we can't use `INTERVAL`, but this is not the last mistake that I made. If we using  `GLOBAL PARTITION` we have to specified `MAXVALUE` for all columns, so we have to add new partition where values are smaller than `MAXVALUE`.

Correct statement to `create unique` index which I mentioned earlier:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX PK_SOME_TABLE ON SOME_TABLE
        (SOME_ID) 
        LOGGING
        TABLESPACE SOME_TABLESPACE            
        GLOBAL PARTITION BY RANGE (SOME_ID)
          (
            PARTITION P_1 VALUES LESS THAN (1000)
            PARTITION P_2 VALUES LESS THAB (MAXVALUE)
          )
        NOPARALLEL;
```